# Adding a hyperlink VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am desperately searching for a solution for my following problem in VBA for Excel:

I want to request user input asking for entering a website link. The code should transfrom this into a hyperlink (like excel does with the HYPERLINK formula). The output should add the word *website* to the ActiveCell with a hyperlink to the input website.

this is my latest approach:

> ```
> Sub add_hyperlink()
>     link = Chr(34) & InputBox("Enter link") & Chr(34)
>     ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=ActiveCell, Address:=link, 
>     ScreenTip:="Follow this link", TextToDisplay:="website"
> End Sub
> ```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is not working with this, exactly? As long as you add the `http(s)://` this appears to be working. Please [edit] your question with a [mcve] so we can better assist you. And welcome to SO!

Comment: And I don't think your double quotation marks are necessary (the `Chr(34)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what is the problem, but this works:

```
Sub add_hyperlink() 
    Dim link As String
    link = InputBox("Enter link")
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add ActiveCell, link, ScreenTip:="Follow this link", TextToDisplay:="Website"
End Sub
```

Comment: OP specifically stated that he wants to add to the `ActiveCell`. Not sure how changing the range to be static solves the problem.

Comment: You're right, edited.